# File Uploaded Can't Press Upload Button - python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have been able to have my file uploaded in the file upload queue; however, I am having diffuculty being able to click the upload button.

I keep receiving the following error:

```text
Exception has occurred: ElementClickInterceptedException
Message: element click intercepted: Element <button data-testid="modal-footer-button-primary" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">...</button> is not clickable at point (945, 650). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-footer">...</div>
```

This is the code:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


#this is used to not let chrome close
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("url")

#to be able to click clayton state 
button1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"name")
button1.click()

#sign into to files usg 
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "UserName")
username.send_keys('username')

password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Password")
password.send_keys('password')

form = driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitButton")
form.submit()

#usg duo push 
button2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "DuoAdfsAdapter")
button2.click()

WebDriverWait(driver,     20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='duo_iframe']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Send Me a Push']"))).click()

#website choosing correct drop down for choice
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "gotofolderform"))).click()

finaid_dd = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "field_gotofolder"))
finaid_dd.select_by_value("value")

 #click the upload button and browse window opens
button3 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "fileUploaderButton")
button3.click()

file_upload = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "file-selector-browse")
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", file_upload) --- don't need this at the moment.

#input file into website

file_input = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "file-selector-input") 
file_path = "filepath"
file_input.send_keys(file_path)
#press upload on website

file_input.submit()
```

This is the html: [image]

I have tried identifying it as a button and nothing will happen. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Is the `Upload` button supposed to have an `id="fileUploaderButton"` attribute? Since you're finding it `By.ID` via, `button3 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "fileUploaderButton")`, or is `button3` a different button?

Comment: @JonnyHenly  button3 is a different button. the button for upload is the one shown in the html screenshot. I am not sure how to identify it. I have tried with button4 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn btn-primary").click() 
I still get errors. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.